# The version of iPhone OS on “” does not match any of the versions of iPhone OS supported for development with this copy of Xcode

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have followed Apples tutorial and upgraded my iphone to 3.0. But i get this error:

OS Installed on 
3.0 (7A341)

Xcode Supported iPhone OS Versions
3.0 (7A312g)
2.2.1

And when i try to run an application on my iphone xcode states:
No provisioned iPhone OS device is connected.

What have I missed?

Comment: Have you run your app on your phone before? if so, try reinstalling your provisioning profile and then do a reboot of your phone

Comment: note: Tested this with building on and iPad 3.2.1 with sdk 3.2.
Yes it installs.
No it doesn't really work, as far as I can tell.
I get a bunch of warnings, but my working app does not load it's view. There's a note on the apple dev site that users whom have upgraded to 3.2.1 or 4.0.1 need to download the new xcode with 4.0.1 sdk.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you need to upgrade xcode to the newest version of the SDK as well as your iPhone / iPod Touch to the newest version of the SDK.  It looks like your XCode is from beta 5 where your iPhone is GM.

Answer (score 13):

Stumbled across this question because I've had the same problem with 3.0.1. Apple has [an advisory (PDF)](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/download.action?path=/iphone/iphone_sdk_3.0__final/iphone_os_3.0.1_advisory_v1.1.pdf) about how to get XCode to stop worrying and love the 3.0.1. It boils down to running a command in Terminal:

```
ln -s /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.0\ \(7A341\) /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.0.1
```

Comment: this is a good tip that can be applied to other versions, too (as long as you're not making use of the changes between different library versions)

Answer (score 3):

Both XCode and the iPhone OS need to be the most recent version to install apps.  In addition, you will need to reenable the iPhone for development after every software upgrade in the XCode device manager.

Answer (score 2):

Look in the organizer window if the phone is in orange state ..then just restart the phone and see.

Answer (score 2):

How To:

Add an iOS SDK from a downloaded Xcode dmg:

1. Download the Xcode version dmg containing the iOS SDK you need
2. Make sure Xcode is not running
3. Double click the downloaded Xcode dmg, right click the Xcode.app icon, choose "Show Package Content"
4. Copy Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/ to /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs (on you local machine)
5. Copy Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/ to /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer (on you local machine)
6. Copy Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/ to /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport (on you local machine)
7. Right click Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/, choose "Make Alias", rename the alias to "Latest"
8. Start Xcode

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this as Pluckyglen said, but will add that this is a way to cheat XCode about the version of the Device.
Creating a unix Symbolic link: 
   `ln -s <´Xcode version´> <´Device Version´>` 
 
makes Xcode think that the device version is a supported version, cause we are making the dev version just a link to one of the supported versions.
At least this is what I understood :P